# express: what is the difference between req.query and req.body

Tags: express

I want to know what is the difference between req.query and req.body?

below is a piece of code where `req.query` is used. what happens if i use `req.body` instead of `req.query`.

below function is called as a result of `$resource` get function. and this function checks whether the user is authenticated or a right user or not

```
function isAuthenticated() {
return compose()
// Validate jwt
.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
  if(req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
    req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token;
  }
  validateJwt(req, res, next);
})
// Attach user to request
.use(function(req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.user._id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return res.send(401);

    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) contains the query params of the request.

For example in `sample.com?foo=bar`, `req.query` would be `{foo:"bar"}`

[req.body](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) contains anything in the request body.  Typically this is used on `PUT` and `POST` requests.

For example a `POST` to  sample.com with the body of `{"foo":"bar"}` and a header of type `application/json`, `req.body` would contain `{foo: "bar"}`

So to answer your question, if you were to use `req.body` instead of `req.query`, it would most likely not find anything in the body, and therefore not be able to validate the jwt.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what about req.params? can you also specify the difference between req.params vs  req.body vs req.query?

Comment: That's a different question and should be asked (or searched for) as such. (params is for url-values, like /user/:id -> req.params.id)

Answer (score 8):

**req.body** is mainly used with form using POST method.
You've to use `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in the form properties. As POST method don't show anything in URL, you have to use body-parser middleware
if the form contains an input text with name="age" then req.body.age return the value of this feld.

**req.query** takes parameters in the URL (mainly GET method)
example for this URL ► http://localhost/books?author=Asimov
`app.get('/books/', (req, res) => { console.log(req.query.author) }` will return Asimov

by the way, **req.params** take the end part of the URL as a parameter.
example for this URL ► http://localhost/books/14
`app.get('/books/:id', (req, res) => { console.log(req.params.id) }` will return 14