# In React Redux-Saga Express Nodejs environment, req.body is undefined in router

Tags: node.js, express, react-redux, redux-saga, body-parser

I have read through other examples of req.body returning undefined on StackOverflow, but have not come across any solutions proposed before that have solved my problem.

I am working in React Express Node.js environment. I have other GET requests to the server that are working, however I have one GET request that returns "undefined" when I log out "req.body" from the router.

My Express server is configured like so:

```
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const sessionMiddleware = require("./modules/session-middleware");

const passport = require("./strategies/user.strategy");

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Route includes
const userRouter = require("./routes/user.router");
const bucketRouter = require("./routes/bucket.router");
const UploaderS3Router = require("react-dropzone-s3-uploader/s3router");
const imageRouter = require("./routes/image.router");

// Passport Session Configuration //
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

// start up passport sessions
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/* Routes */
app.use("/api/user", userRouter);
app.use("/api/user", bucketRouter);
app.use("/api/imageurl", imageRouter);

//aws route
app.use(
  "/s3",
  UploaderS3Router({
    bucket: "annesbucket", // required
    region: "us-east-2", // optional
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }, // optional
    ACL: "public-read", // this is the default - set to `public-read` to let anyone view uploads
  })
);

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static("build"));

// App Set //
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

/** Listen * */
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

I am using redux saga to make the GET request and to pass the payload from the req.body to the server, and it looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { put, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* getPhotosExperiences(action) {
  try {
    const userID = action.payload.userID;

    const config = {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      withCredentials: true,
    };
    const response = yield axios.get(
      `/api/imageurl/photoexperience/${userID}`,
      action.payload
      //   config
    );
    console.log(action.payload);
    yield put({
      type: "SET_PHOTOS_EXPERIENCES",
      payload: response.data,
    });
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error getting list items:", err);
  }
}

function* getPhotosExperiencesSaga() {
  yield takeLatest("GET_PHOTOS_EXPERIENCES", getPhotosExperiences);
  console.log("getPhotosExperiences fired off");
}

export default getPhotosExperiencesSaga;
```

Again, when I log out "action.payload" in my saga I'm seeing the data that I want to pass to the server.

The GET request that is not recognizing req.body is in a router that is registered in the server as imageRouter.

This is my GET request:

```
router.get("/photoexperience/:userID", rejectUnauthenticated, (req, res) => {
  console.log(
    "this is what the server is getting:",
    req.body.userID,
    req.body.experienceID
  );
  console.log("req.params.id is:", req.params.id);
  console.log("this is req:", req);
  const experienceID = req.body.experienceID;
  const queryText = `SELECT "user_photos_experiences".experience_id, "user_photos_experiences".photo_id, "photos".experience_photo
  FROM "user_photos_experiences"
   JOIN "photos" ON "user_photos_experiences".photo_id = "photos".id WHERE "user_photos_experiences".experience_id = $1`;
  pool
    .query(queryText, [experienceID])
    .then((responseDB) => {
      const dbRows = responseDB.rows;
      console.table(dbRows);
      res.send(dbRows);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error getting photos from photoexperience:", err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

I'd appreciate another set of eyes on this -- it's been stumping me for many hours!

TLDR; I am wondering how I can access the payload I sent out from my saga from within my server side router.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem in case anyone else runs into something similar using PostgreSQL. Instead of storing my experience on req.body, I needed to store it on req.query, ie:

```
router.get("/photoexperience/:userID", rejectUnauthenticated, (req, res) => {
  console.log(
    "this is what the server is getting:",
    req.query.userID,
    req.query.experienceID
  );
  console.log(req.query);
  // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  const userID = req.query.userID;
  const queryText = `SELECT "user_photos_experiences".experience_id, "user_photos_experiences".photo_id, "photos".experience_photo, "user_photos_experiences".user_id
  FROM "user_photos_experiences"
   JOIN "photos" ON "user_photos_experiences".photo_id = "photos".id WHERE "user_photos_experiences".user_id = $1;`;
  pool
    .query(queryText, [userID])
    .then((responseDB) => {
      const dbRows = responseDB.rows;
      console.table(dbRows);
      res.send(dbRows);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error getting photos from photoexperience:", err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

This fixed my GET request :) Information on the difference between req.body and req.query was answered here: [express: what is the difference between req.query and req.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915424/express-what-is-the-difference-between-req-query-and-req-body).